# Differentiation based on two columns values - Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have the following challenge.

The best thing you can do is look at the photo so you can understand it better. I want to dynamically display in Google Spreadsheet a distinction between booking appointments.

**The following appointments exist:** =
New Sales & Winback.

1. **New Sales** = It is a new appointment, if there was none before, so there is no "lead_id" or if there is already the "lead_id", the appointment must be longer than 30 days in the past.
2. **Winback** = If the same "lead_id" is booked again within 30 days.

---

So I want if "lead_id" exists, then the last date from the "lead_id" -> "oppt_booked_on" minus the current date "oppt_booked_on".

---

I have tried a lot, vlookp, match function etc. But I just can't manage to write a dynamic formula. It is also important that always the last booking is used, like in the example (photo).
I hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

Comment: A picture is not very helpful. As things stand, you are expecting one of the volunteer contributors here to open a new spreadsheet themselves and then enter your data into it before they can even begin to consider thinking about a solution, developing it and then testing it. Consider sharing a link to a spreadsheet containing your sample data. There is clearly nothing confidential in it, so there should be no conflict in doing that.

Comment: About sharing spreadsheets, do note that [it exposes your email address](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/). So, use a dummy Google account if you consider your email address to be private. While external links are welcome, consider adding a [table](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/) to show your data structure.

Comment: Sharing a spreadsheet does not expose your email address if you share it as "View only" or "Comment only," which is all that is necessary.

Comment: This could have been solved with one formula (i.e., without the need of helper columns). But it was not an efficient use of time for me to hand-enter data myself in order to work it up and test it. If you still would like the single-formula approach, feel free to share a link to a sample spreadsheet (set to "View only" if you like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is entirely what you're looking for, but the following formula:

```
=datedif(index(sort(filter(F:F,A:A=A2)),match(F2,sort(filter(F:F,A:A=A2)),0)-1),F2,"d")
```

in the 'Days between_booked on' column (your column J) will return the number of days between the row's date, and the date of the previous instance of the same lead_id (column A).

Thereafter, the following formula:

```
=if(and(countif(A:A,A2)>1,isbetween(J2,1,30)),"Winback","New Sales")
```

in the 'Outcome' (your column I) will return "Winback" if there are more than 1 instances of the lead_id of the current row, and the duration between the current row and the previous instance of the same lead_id is less than or equal to 30 days.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it makes sense, but here is the script:

```
function main() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const range = sh.getDataRange();
  const [header, ...rows] = range.getValues();

  // get indexes of the columns
  const col = {};
  col.id      = header.indexOf('lead_id')
  col.outcome = header.indexOf('Outcome');
  col.date    = header.indexOf('oppt_booked_on');
  col.days    = header.indexOf('Days Between booked_on');

  
  // create the object 'data' from the rows
    
  const data = {};
  for (let row in rows) {
    let id = rows[row][col.id];
  
    try {
      data[id].dates.push(rows[row][col.date]);
    }
    catch(e) {
      data[id] = {
        outcome: 'New Sales',
        days: '',
        dates: [rows[row][col.date]],
      }
    }
  }
  
  // change the rows
  
  for (let row in rows) {
    let id = rows[row][col.id];
    let obj = data[id];

    rows[row][col.outcome] = obj.outcome;
    rows[row][col.days] = obj.days;

    if (obj.dates.length > 1) {
      obj.days = days_between(obj.dates.shift(), obj.dates[0]);
      obj.outcome = (obj.days < 30) ? 'Winback' : 'New Sales';
    }
  }

  // set the columns 'Outcome' and 'Days...' on the sheet

  const outcome = rows.map(x => [x[col.outcome]]);
  sh.getRange(2, col.outcome+1, outcome.length, 1).setValues(outcome);

  const days = rows.map(x => [x[col.days]]);
  sh.getRange(2, col.days+1, days.length, 1).setValues(days);

}


// function returns number of days between two dates

function days_between(date1, date2) {
  let msec = Math.abs(date1.getTime() - date2.getTime());
  let days = Math.floor(msec/(1000*60*60*24));
  return days;
}
```

Feel free to modify it for your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

#### Lead Analysis

I'd like to have data that I could copy and paste to test this code:

```
function leadAnalysis() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 6).getValues();
  let lo = { lA: [] };
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!lo.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      lo[r[0]] = [];
      lo[r[0]].push({ lead_id: r[0], lead_name: r[1], booked_by: r[2], cars_on_search: r[3], sales_segment: r[4], oppt_booked_on: r[5], digital_consulant: r[6], 'Outcome': 'New Sales', days_between_booked_on: 0 });
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 9,1,2).setValues([[lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].Outcome,lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].days_between_booked_on]]);
      lo.lA.push(r[0]);
    } else {
      let d = DiffInDays1(new Date(lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length - 1].oppt_booked_on), new Date(r[5]))
      lo[r[0]].push({ lead_id: r[0], lead_name: r[1], booked_by: r[2], cars_on_search: r[3], sales_segment: r[4], oppt_booked_on: r[5], digital_consulant: r[6], 'Outcome': (d > 30) ? 'New Sales' : 'WinBack', days_between_booked_on: d });
      sh.getRange(i + sr, 9,1,2).setValues([[lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].Outcome,lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].days_between_booked_on]]);
    }
  })
}
function DiffInDays1(Day1, Day2) {
  if (Day1 && Day2 && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day1) === '[object Date]') && (Object.prototype.toString.call(Day2) === '[object Date]')) {
    var day = 86400000;
    var t1 = new Date(Day1).valueOf();
    var t2 = new Date(Day2).valueOf();
    var d = Math.abs(t2 - t1);
    var days = Math.floor(d / day);
    //Logger.log(days);
    return days;
  } else {
    throw 'Invalid Inputs';
  }
}
```

Obtained the following data as shown below from my own input:

| lead_id |  |  |  |  | oppt_booked_on |  |  | Outcome | Days |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id1 |  |  |  |  | 1/1/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 0 |
| id2 |  |  |  |  | 1/2/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 0 |
| id3 |  |  |  |  | 1/3/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 0 |
| id4 |  |  |  |  | 1/4/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 0 |
| id5 |  |  |  |  | 1/5/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 0 |
| id6 |  |  |  |  | 1/6/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 0 |
| id1 |  |  |  |  | 3/1/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 59 |
| id2 |  |  |  |  | 3/2/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 59 |
| id3 |  |  |  |  | 3/3/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 59 |
| id4 |  |  |  |  | 3/4/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 59 |
| id5 |  |  |  |  | 3/5/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 59 |
| id6 |  |  |  |  | 3/6/2021 |  |  | New Sales | 59 |
| id1 |  |  |  |  | 3/18/2021 |  |  | WinBack | 16 |
| id2 |  |  |  |  | 3/19/2021 |  |  | WinBack | 16 |
| id3 |  |  |  |  | 3/20/2021 |  |  | WinBack | 16 |
| id4 |  |  |  |  | 3/21/2021 |  |  | WinBack | 16 |
| id5 |  |  |  |  | 3/22/2021 |  |  | WinBack | 16 |
| id6 |  |  |  |  | 3/23/2021 |  |  | WinBack | 16 |

This version will run much faster:

```
function leadAnalysis() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const sr = 2;//data start row
  const vs = sh.getRange(sr, 1, sh.getLastRow() - sr + 1, 6).getValues();
  let lo = { lA: [] };
  let oA = [];
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (!lo.hasOwnProperty(r[0])) {
      lo[r[0]] = [];
      lo[r[0]].push({ lead_id: r[0], lead_name: r[1], booked_by: r[2], cars_on_search: r[3], sales_segment: r[4], oppt_booked_on: r[5], digital_consulant: r[6], 'Outcome': 'New Sales', days_between_booked_on: 0 });
      //sh.getRange(i + sr, 9,1,2).setValues([[lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].Outcome,lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].days_between_booked_on]]);
      oA.push([lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].Outcome,lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].days_between_booked_on])
      lo.lA.push(r[0]);
    } else {
      let d = DiffInDays1(new Date(lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length - 1].oppt_booked_on), new Date(r[5]))
      lo[r[0]].push({ lead_id: r[0], lead_name: r[1], booked_by: r[2], cars_on_search: r[3], sales_segment: r[4], oppt_booked_on: r[5], digital_consulant: r[6], 'Outcome': (d > 30) ? 'New Sales' : 'WinBack', days_between_booked_on: d });
      //sh.getRange(i + sr, 9,1,2).setValues([[lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].Outcome,lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].days_between_booked_on]]);
      oA.push([lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].Outcome,lo[r[0]][lo[r[0]].length-1].days_between_booked_on]);
    }
  })
  sh.getRange(sr,9,oA.length,oA[0].length).setValues(oA)
}
```

Comment: It looks complicated but once you do it a few times on your own you will find it to be quite powerful.  It is essentially what pivot tables do for us.

Comment: Normally, one has to go through one loop to get the data and then another loop to diplay it but since we always only needed access to the last line it was possible to incorporate it into the same loop.